# Number of walks of length $l$ with restriction on edge visits

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Assume you want to build something out of Lego:

- You have N different *types* of lego.
- You have an unlimited amount of every type.
- Any *type* has a unique ID and a set of M>0 connectors, each of a *connection type c*.
- You can connect two lego pieces, if they have connectors of matching (let's assume: the same) type that are not in use already.
- An assembly of lego pieces consists of any number of pieces that are connected.
- Every piece in your set can be connected to any other piece either directly or via a path of intermediate pieces.
- Assume that these are the only constraints: If there is a free, matching connector-pair between lego pieces, you can always connect them. (There is no such thing as collisions, ...)

My question: How many different assemblies of length **l** can you build?

My thought process:

- An assembly of pieces can be described as undirected graph **A**.
- Let's create a graph **C** (I call it *connectivity graph*) in which every *type* of lego is represented by a node and for every pair of matching connectors between types, there is an edge in the graph.
- We know that **C** is a connected graph. However, we cannot assume it is fully connected.
- Self-loops in **C** are possible.
- I would like to map a walk in **C** to a unique assembly graph **A**. However, as long as loops in **A** are allowed, the mapping seems to be non-unique.

I failed coming closer to a solution without taking my first assumption: The assembly graph must be a chain. Then:

- If connections (=connector-pairs) could be used multiple times, the problem would be describing the number of walks of length l in the connectivity graph. (Because loops are no longer possible, unfolding the walk to an assembly graph should be trivial)
- As connector-pairs can only be used once, the same edge can never be used twice in a row in a path. Whenever a node is visited, a new lego piece of it's type is added to the assembly - so visiting an edge again later in the walk would mean "walking on copies" of the nodes, which would work again.
- So: How to find the number of walks of length **l** in graph **C** that do not include the same edge twice in a row.

EDIT: I changed the last to points regarding visiting edges twice (in a row) because I previously had a misconception. I think the assumption now is more reasonable.

If the above is not solvable, would these simplifications make it significantly easier?

- Every node in **C** is connected to itself.
- Consider only assemblies with a tree-structure.
- If using trees only, answer the question for a single starting piece that is only connected to one other piece.
- Consider only assemblies with a chain-structure like I did.

No idea if this problem is solvable, to me it sounds like there should be a solution, but my expertise in Graph Theory is by far not sufficient for that, so I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: What do you mean by an uneven amount of times ?

Comment: I mean {1, 3, 5, 7, ...} times.

Comment: But thinking about it, I think this assumption is not achieving what I wanted it to achieve - I thought it would help prevent using the same connector-pair twice, but apparently it does not. I was stuck in thinking about a special case there. (See editet post, I removed the "uneven" assumption)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the number of walks of length $k$ between any pair of vertices in a graph by raising the adjacency matrix to the $k$-th power. To avoid duplicated edges, we will create a new graph. Consider your original graph as directed (each edge correspond two a directed edge in both direction). For each directed edge, create a vertex in your new graph. A vertex $e_1$ is linked to a vertex $e_2$ if the edges $e_1$ and $e_2$ are consecutive (and distinct) in the original graph. This construction is called the line graph. A walk in the original walk that avoid passing two times in a row on the same edge is equivalent to a a walk in the new directed graph. This solves the case where the build is a chain.

For an efficient computation of $A^k$ (with $A$ the adjacency matrix), you can use exponentiation by squaring, yielding an $\mathcal{O}(n^\omega\log(n))$, with $\omega$ the exponent of matrix multiplication and $n$ the size of the graph

The more general problem where the build is not restricted to a chain seems to be much more difficult.